# Atrifactory Pro's feature: Repository Replication

Tags: artifactory

JFrog Artifactory Pro has `Repository Replication` feature. How ever one Artifactory Pro license only allow to install one instance on one server host. So if I want to use the `Repository Replication` function, I have to at least buy two Pro license, is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when configuring a replication (push/pull) between 2 Artifactory instances both of them are required to have a valid Artifactory Pro license.

Comment: Hi. I noticed that a `JFrog Artifactory Enterprise` pack include 3 licenses. As far as I understand, 3 licenses are used for `High Availability Feature` which need 3 servers(is this right?) . Is it possible that I buy one Enterprise pack and not use the `HA` feature, just set 3 servers in 3 cities?

Comment: You can use the enterprise pack without the HA feature to setup servers in 3 different locations.